# Publish selected files ASP.NET, Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, file, publish, selected

I have a ASP.NET Web Application

Is there any way we can publish only selected files from Visual Studio 2008.

I have already published the site, now I have made some modifications to some of the code files and I want to publish only few code files not all the changed files..

Is there any way we can achieve this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Publish Web screen, if you choose "Replace matching files with local copies" instead of "Delete all existing files prior to publish" then it will only publish the files that are different.

In your case, if you changed some of the code and publish with the "Replace..." option, then it will simply replace the existing DLL for your web application with a newly compiled one and should leave everything else alone.

But... I think you're saying that you don't want to deploy **all** of your changes. This is what source control is for. You should check out the code at whatever revision or branch you want to publish for and then publish it.

Comment: yeah what you said makes sense for me but unfortunately our development environment has no source control set up :( I just joined here.. so looking for some possibilities. Well, I think if I can exclude the file which I don't want to publish and publish using "Replace matching files with local copies" that might solve the issue.. please advise me ?..