# Excluded folder in project - Publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I would like to ask a question about the web deployment method in *Visual Studio 2012*.

In our development server, we have a specific folder in `/inetpub/wwwroot/` with `W+R` permissions. This folder is used to store uploaded files.

On the prod server , we have the same folder as you could imagine.

When we publish our local changes to Dev server, on the console, we see that *VS2012* delete folders and files before publishing the new ones.

So my question is, if we exclude a folder by right-clicking on it and do "exclude from project", and then publish the project, **will it also delete the excluded folder on the development server** ?

We have limited access on these servers so we don't want to "try and see".

Comment: What do you publish settings look like? Seems like you have set "delete all existing files prior to publish" .. ?

Comment: the option "delete all existing files prior to publish" is checked when publishing.

Comment: that's the problem. select the other option, "replace matching files.."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publish selected files ASP.NET, Visual Studio 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206274/publish-selected-files-asp-net-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will also delete the folders excluded from the project from the server if "Delete all existing files prior to publish" is set (tested using VS2013).